# Barchi Nafshi on Rosh Hashana

Tags: tefilla, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Why don't we say Barchi Nafshi on Rosh Hashanah like we say it on all other Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: Perhaps we say למנצח לבני קרח instead

Comment: Same for Hallel, and all the other Rosh Chodesh liturgy

Comment: @DoubleAA please explain what you mean. Hallel I understand why we don't say. What other Rosh Chodesh liturgy are you referring to. And what are we not saying

Comment: ראשי חדשים לעמך נתת... ובראשי חדשיכם תקריבו עולה לה'...לחיים ולשלום ביום ראש החודש הזה...

Comment: What I remember from my Rebbeim is that Hashem Himself blesses Rosh Chodesh Tishrei/Rosh HaShannah, and with that blessing then we take from it through the year and bless the other months as Klal Yisroel. But the first one needs Hashem to do it for us.

Comment: Why do we say it on Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: @shmosel, I don’t know, but it’s not in my siddur (Frankfurt a/M variant of Western Ashkenaz)

Answer (score 0):

In order to confuse the Satan, we don’t make rosh hashana into Rosh Chodesh. For the same reason, we don’t read parshas bereishis, despite being the start of the year. {For a comprehensive explanation of this idea, see Likkutei Sichos chelek chof daled, page 222 ff.}

Comment: The reading of the parshes do not necessarily have to with the beginning and end of the year. We use a system that finishes once a year there use to be a system that finished every three years.

Comment: I know, I’m saying the reason that it was set up like that in the first place.